# Can the climber jetpack to a buried tile?

Tags: forbidden-desert

In Forbidden Desert the climber's card says that they can move to any blocked tile, whereas the jetpack says it can only be used to fly to an unblocked tile.

Can the climber use the jetpack to travel to a blocked tile?

We just played a game and went by the ruling in [this thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1073527/the-climber-and-the-jetpack), which allowed it, but it would be nice if someone can point out a more official ruling (or even a thread where the conclusion is more confident!)

Comment: I am not familiar with the game, but I would infer the opposite. If the jetpack takes you to any unblocked tile, it takes you to any **unblocked** tile. The climber does not make blocked tiles unblocked, thus they would not be eligible targets for the jetpack.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.  Other cases where players special abilities combine (Navigator and Climber) or where a player's special ability combines with equipment (Explorer and Dune Blaster) are explicitly mentioned.  The Climber says they can move to blocked spaces, not that they treat blocked spaces as unblocked. So I don't see anything that suggests you would be able to modify the jet pack's explicit statement that you can only move to unblocked tiles.

Answer (score 1):

It's not official, but there is a (fan-created) FAQ post on BGG now [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1127034/rules-faq). It states (towards the end) that the Climber is allowed to use the Jetpack to travel to a blocked tile.

Comment: And a number of people in the comments disagreed with him...

Comment: thanks for the link to the FAQ, that cleared up a number of questions I had

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could reference the rule book, but they do not explicitly state the use of equipment with your special ability. So personally, I'd say play by your own house rules.

However, in this specific case I do not think this matchup is allowed. As you mentioned, the card does state to move to an unblocked tile specifically which basically is the answer to your question right there.

Also every equipment card has 3 stipulations listed at the bottom:

- Play at any time
- Does not count as an action
- Discard to box after use

Since it doesn't count as an action and can be played at anytime, I feel that also kind of discourages away from mixing equipment with special abilities.

Forbidden Desert is a great, short game to play on a rainy day, however I think the company needs to clean up it's rulebook and add some much needed clarity.

Happy gaming!